# Is the ring of integers modulo n, $\mathbb{Z_n}$, an ordered ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers, ordered-rings

I'm starting to study on my own some basic group theory, maybe this is a very basic question, but I can't find any answer on the internet. I would like to know if the **ring of integers modulo n**, $\mathbb{Z_n}$, is an **ordered ring**.

For example, if $3,4\in\mathbb{Z_{10}}$, does it make sense the expression: $3<4$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$?

If $\mathbb{Z_n}$, is an **ordered ring**: is there any equivalent definition of absolute value, like in the rings of integers $Z$?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not. In an ordered ring, if $a\lt b$, then $a+c\lt b+c$ for all $c$. But if $0\lt 1$, then you get $0\lt n-1$ by repeatedly adding $1$ and using transitivity, and then you add $1$ and get $1\lt n=0$.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin for your answer, I know understand that it is not an ordered ring. Cheers!